# Liquibase configuration to run different sql scripts test vs prod

Tags: maven, liquibase

Is there a way to configure liquibase  to run different sql scripts test vs prod with maven?

Comment: That seems like a bad idea, then you haven't necessarily run and tested those scripts before trying to do so in prod. This may be an XY problem; what's the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: To add dummy data into the test database and to avoid doing that in prod environment.

Comment: Perhaps that should be a separate task to migrating? This is usually referred to as *seeding*.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem you can use Liquibase context. It allows you to execute only specific changeSets which are related to the provided context.

For maven you can use `-Dliquibase.contexts=test_context`

If you have a Spring applications, you can use `spring.liquibase.contexts=test_context`

And in changeSets set `context` attribute:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bat" context="text_context">
   <!-- your logic here -->
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Here's a link that may help as well: https://www.liquibase.org/2014/11/contexts-vs-labels.html  It is context vs labels and outlines the way liquibase can control which script in which environment will get ran, and includes when to use either context, label, or both.